# Adding attribute to menu - page specific

Tags: routes

Hi I know I can alter menu links classes/attributes using theme_menu_link() function.
But from what I can see, there is no way to determine what current page is being rendered from within the function.

i.e. I have a wep app that loads in 4 pages (ajax) and you can swipe to change page. I need to add an attribute on each menu link and they differ depending on the page.

Question being, how can I determine page from within theme_menu_link();

Regards

Comment: You can use $path = $_GET['q']; using this you can get the path of the page you are in !

Comment: returns 'node'.

Comment: When you are in front page you see "node" in other pages you will see exact path !

Answer (score 0):

found it,

```
$page = arg(0);
```

cheers anyways